# Layout access without create a new class in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a novice programmer and I'm working on one of the my first projects on Android Studio. 
Is it possible to access a .xml file without create a new java class? If I have two or more layouts, in which way can I switch between them with only the main class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not clear.
`setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);` sets the activity with .XML file. So adding the buttons to your layouts you can play with that